# FreeSwitch mod_callcenter xml_curl configuration

Tags: php, freeswitch

how can we change the mod_callcenter configuration dynamically in Freeswitch using xml_curl.

can anybody give me some example configuration in php ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure mod_xml_curl to attempt to pull config data from your xml api for all modules:

```
<configuration name="xml_curl.conf" description="cURL XML Gateway">
  <bindings> 
    <binding name="configuration"> 
      <param name="gateway-url" value="http://example.com:8080/fsapi" bindings="configuration"/> 
    </binding> 
  </bindings> 
</configuration>
```

You can configure your PHP script to dump the content of `$_REQUEST` to see exactly what parameters are provided for mod_callcenter.

Once you know what parameters you are working with, you can respond to the request with the same XML you would otherwise have in your static file.

If you receive a request that is not for mod_callcenter, you can return the following response to cause FreeSwitch to read from the static files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<document type="freeswitch/xml">
  <section name="result">
    <result status="not found"/>
  </section>
</document>
```

Comment: HI mgwilliams, thanks for your answer.

Any Example php code will be really helpful.

Comment: Hi user2015570, I've not worked with PHP in many years, so I'm afraid I can't offer any code. The FS wiki does have examples in some other languages: https://freeswitch.org/confluence/dosearchsite.action?queryString=xml_curl